# Where to upload JavaScript file in WordPress

Tags: javascript, uploads

I am using the [headers and footers plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/)  to call a small script I made by pasting the script directly into the user interface of the plugin. However, I would like to upload a JS file and call that instead.

Where should I upload the file? My guess would be the child theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper Javascript Implementation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81693/proper-javascript-implementation)

Comment: Uploading JS to the media library isn't supported, you're going to have to upload the file to the server itself and modify the PHP code to load it

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You will want to enqueue your scripts using [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) and then upload them into your child theme.  I normally create a `/js/` directory to keep things organized.

Here is a sample of how to enqueue a file inside of a themes JS subfolder.

```
function wpse_enqueue_scripts() {    

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'js-functions',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/js/functions.js')
    );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_enqueue_scripts', 999);
```

Comment: Even with the plugin, I have to use the wp_enqueue_scripts? I thought the plugin is supposed to take care of that for you.

Comment: I don't know anything about that plugin, you made it sound like you wanted to do it yourself instead of using the plugin.